# How to make a hyphen, not minus sign, when using expression() to label in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, plotmath

I'm using `expression()` in my plot's x-axis label to create a square-root symbol over my measure's name to indicate that the data has been transformed using square-root transformation. However, my measure's name ("CES-D") has a hyphen in it. When I write it in the `expression()`, the hyphen becomes a minus or *en dash* character with space around it.

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + 
    labs(x = expression(sqrt(CES-D~scores)), 
         y = "CES-D scores")
```

[image: Hyphens different in x and y axis labels]

Notice the hyphens are different in the x and y axis labels. In the x-axis label, it looks like square root of "CES minus D scores".

How do I make a regular hyphen character inside an `expression()` for text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try backticks around `CES-D`:

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + labs(x = expression(sqrt(`CES-D`~scores)), y = "CES-D scores")
```

Comment: Not working in my case. Is it because i'm a windows user?

Comment: @Koray works fine for me on OS X and Windows.